# How do I override an .xml file in a Joomla component?

Tags: user, overrides, registration, xml, profile

I’d like to override some files (.php and .xml) in */components/com_users/models*. Can this even be done? Or should I try and make a modified/renamed copy of *com_users*?

What I am trying to do is: Remove the *name* field from the user profile and registration forms, replacing it with *firstname* and *lastname*. I also need to modify *registration.php* and *profile.php*, so that they stich together a *name* from `$firstname . ' ' . $lastname`, because Joomla relies on *name* to be set to something meaningful.

This actually works if I edit the respective files directly, but my changes will be lost with an upgrade to Joomla. **How can I avoid this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check Joomla Plugins and Events.

There are such events like `onContentPrepareForm($form, $data)` and *(may be you'll want to use `onContentPrepareData($context, $data)` but you should be fine with the first one)* where you can get `$data` and `$form` and modify the form in there with your own XML, like:

```
    /** @var JForm $form */
    $form->loadFile(dirname(__FILE__).'/custom/form.xml',true);
```

It will do override that you need.

And if you dig deep you'll be able to find some triggers in user store algorithm like `onUserBeforeSave($user, $isnew, $data)` where you can adjust current data with getting data from the request.

But if you'll be working not with `user` it may be a solution two just use system event like `onAfterRoute` like this:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->input->set('name',JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('firstname').' '.JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('lastname'));
```